# Dart: unable to create X509Certificate ASN1 from Bytes stored in assets

Tags: flutter, dart, certificate, x509, asn.1

I try reading a certificate from resources in Dart,

```
// using this helper function
Future<Uint8List> loadUint8List(String key, { bool cache = true }) async {
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(key);
      if (data == null)
        return null;

      if (data.lengthInBytes < 50 * 1024) {
        return data.buffer.asUint8List();
      }
    }

await loadUint8List("assets/raw_data/certificates/sealgen_dets27_ec256")
          .then((list) {
    var asn1 = asnLib.ASN1Sequence.fromBytes(liat);
    var cert = X509Certificate.fromAsn1(asn1);

 }
```

But get this Error while creating a X509Certificate (object is from the x509 library) from an ASN1Sequence:

**Bad state: Unable to get name of ObjectIdentifier with nodes [1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 7]**

Can anyone help?